# DataMapper datatype

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

Just want to know what are the corresponding datatype that I should declare when using DataMapper.

Types in MySQL

- smallint
- bit
- varchar

Can anyone tell me the corresponding type in DataMapper?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But I did tag it as DataMapper. Added a Ruby tag

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://datamapper.org/docs/dm_more/types.html) you are fairly limited with no specific equivalents. Varchar somewhat equals string and integer seems to take the place of bigint. Bit is not mentioned at all.  The idea is born out further by [this link](http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-reflection/0.11.1/DataMapper/Reflection/MysqlAdapter#get_type-instance_method) (click on show source) where you will see the adapter for MySQL maps the data types similar to above. Again, bit is not mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. Actually bit is my biggest concern. I am using Boolean for it but don't know if it's good enough.

Comment: I guess you could do some sort of bitwise process using a series of Boolean if it came to it but that seems a bit cumbersome.